# Recursion relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

How does one show that $I_n=\int\limits_0^1 (1-x^2)^ndx $ satisfies the recursion relation $I_n={2n\over 2n+1}I_{n-1}$? I don't think I have to explicitly evaluate the integral right?

Thanks.

Comment: @DidierPiau: Ah, well-spotted typo! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You just verify this integrating by parts: for $n\geq 1$
$$
I_n = \int_0^1 (1-x^2)^n\,dx = x(1-x^2)^n\mid^1_0 + 2n\int\limits_{0}^1(1-x^2)x^2\,dx = 
$$
$$
=  0 +2n\int\limits_{0}^1(1-x^2)^{n-1}(x^2-1)\,dx + 2n I_{n-1} = 2nI_{n-1} - 2nI_n
$$
by expressing $I_n$ we have $I_n = \frac{2n}{2n+1}I_{n-1}$. There should be a typo in a $-$ sign as Didier told you.

Comment: One has to "explicitly evaluate the integral" $I_0$, which has the value $1$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: why is it needed?

Comment: Sorry for my first comment. He indeed didn't ask for $I_0$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: nevermind)

Answer (score 3):

Start with
$$
     \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x} \left( x \left(1-x^2\right)^n \right) = \left(2n+1\right) \left(1-x^2\right)^n - 2 n \left(1-x^2\right)^{n-1}
$$
Assuming $n > 0$, and integrating both sides from 0 to 1 we get:
$$
   0 = (2n+1) I_n - 2n I_{n-1}
$$
Clearly, $I_0 = \int_0^1 \mathrm{d} x = 1$.